# I want to show tables when radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, show-hide

I am trying to show tables onClick or onSelect of a couple of checkboxes.  I have a checkbox for 'standard' which, when selected, should display a table of standard options, and I have a checkbox for 'customized' which, when selected, should display a table of customized options.

Right now the tables toggle but won't show at the same time.  In other words, if both are checked, I need both tables to display, one under the other.  If only 'standard' is checked, then only 'standard' options show, and if only 'customized' is checked, then only 'customized' options show.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tcRD/2/

Here is my JS:

```
function toggleTables(which)
{

    if(which == "1") {
        document.getElementById('customize').style.display = "table";
        document.getElementById('standard').style.display = "none";

        }
    if(which == "2") {
        document.getElementById('standard').style.display = "table";
        document.getElementById('customize').style.display = "none";

        }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="customize_1" onClick="toggleTables('2')" value="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1"></label> Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" id="customize_0" onClick="toggleTables('1')" value="checkbox" checked="checked" />
Customize


<br />
<table width="100%" class="imagetable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="customize">
    <tr><td>customize</td></tr>                   
</table>

<table width="100%" class="imagetable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="standard" style="display: none">
    <tr><td>standard</td></tr>                   
</table>
```

Please give me a hand. - UPDATED WITH CHECKBOXES**

Comment: If you're using radio buttons how to you expect to pick two at one time? Use checkboxes.

Comment: In your html you are using radio button and in question you are saying check box?Which 1 is correct?

Comment: Even in function toggletable() if you select both what value will you pass? You have not written anything for both..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can just check the status of checkbox within function.

```
function toggleTables()
{
    var isCustomize = document.getElementById('customize_1').checked; 
    var isStandard = document.getElementById('standard_1').checked;  

    var customize = document.getElementById('customize'); 
    var standard = document.getElementById('standard');    

    customize.style.display = isCustomize  ? 'table' : 'none';
    standard.style.display = isStandard  ? 'table' : 'none';
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4tcRD/3/